# Ionic swipe back on certain div element instead of ion-view with animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, swipe, ionic-framework

I know that Ionic supports native like swipe back animations between views simply by using the `can-swipe-back` attribute of the `ion-view` element. Does anyone know if there is a way to allow the swiping only for a certain `div` container within the `ion-view` element?

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic you can define any element with the swipe attribute:

```
<div on-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" class="button">
    <!-- some html -->
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.onSwipeLeft = function() {
    // Do anything, like going back in history
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
}
```

Comment: You are right that would be possible BUT I want to have the typical swiping animation between views. By that I mean that as soon as I start dragging I want to see how the old view disappears and the new one appears like immediate reaction to the swiping. I don't want to call `goBack()` after the swiping has finished.